# Which font is used in this image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts, font-design

[image]

What font is this ? Can anyone help me to find the font used in this image ?

Comment: Please take a look at https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083 and also [ask] and [answer] a question to get a sense both of applicable questions for this venue and how to frame them to get best responses. Once you've looked those over, I suggest you edit to bring your query in line with our font identification question guidelines, or it might well get closed - it already has at least one close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the base is [Girls are Weird](https://www.dafont.com/es/girls-are-weird.font?fpp=100&psize=l&text=PART) font with some modifications, keep in mind this typeface is used in embroidery and perhaps the image of the question has some distortion:

[image]

Similar to [Boyz R Gross](https://www.dafont.com/boyzrgross.font?text=PART&psize=l)

[image]

See them at [The Crazy Dazy Fonts](http://blog.thecrazydazy.com/TheCrazyDazyFonts/index.html)